# Slow Collections.unmodifiableList()

Tags: java, list, collections

I have very strange behavior of Collections.unmodifiableList() function.
I have an algorithm, In which I am working with ArrayList of POJO objects, taking subList() of it and iterating through it. The problem is that If I wrapping this list with Collections.unmodifiableList() the algorithm became 2x slower. 
Literally, only one change is wrapping the array with the unmodifiable interface. Breath profiling with JProfiler shows, that two things become very slow: iterator.hasNext() and iterator.next()

What can be the problem? From source code of UnmodifiableRandomAccessList I see only one level wrapping of all methods. I can't believe, that this can give such degradation run time.

Comment: why do you use unmodifiableList? Are there mutators in your algorithm? Is it possible that those mutators try to modify list state and exceptions (which are expensive) are produced?

Comment: I think we need to see your code. Are you sure you aren't inadvertently wrapping multiple times for example?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that with the extra delegation, the JVM cannot inline the methods, which results in code jumps which kill the CPU pipelining. What I don't like about this 'theory' is that it is a bit too far fetched. You can potentially check this with [JITWatch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html).

Comment: @Cootri no, there is no mutators in the algorithm. In some places in the program, I can work  only with unmodifiable lists to follow invariants of some classes. But now, for performance testing, I separated this part of the program and can use both unmodifiable and modifiable lists.